# Chrome returns status code 400 in docker container

Tags: docker, selenium, google-chrome, protractor, headless

I have protractor selenium tests running in a docker container. I have to test an insecure website. For one of the functions where API call is made to get some data back from backed chrome returns status code 400. I have added the following in my protractor config file:

chrome args `("--headless", "--no-sandbox", "--disable-dev-shm-usage")`

```
directConnection: true,
disableChecks: true
```

Capabilities:

```
acceptInsecureCerts: true
acceptSslCerts: true
```

I have also added following in my .env file:

```
NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0
```

Below are the network logs I`ve gotten:

```
{
  method: 'Network.responseReceived',
  params: {
    frameId: '721A00F872D1255AA1DAE58D2DF5D75E',
    loaderId: '70EAE0F82B0AB6BDE6489BC26D77DA34',
    requestId: '117.239',
    response: {
      connectionId: 309,
      connectionReused: true,
      encodedDataLength: 123,
      fromDiskCache: false,
      fromPrefetchCache: false,
      fromServiceWorker: false,
      headers: [Object],
      mimeType: 'application/problem+json',
      protocol: 'h2',
      remoteIPAddress: 'remote ip',
      remotePort: 443,
      securityDetails: [Object],
      securityState: 'insecure',
      status: 400,
      statusText: '',
      timing: [Object],
      url: 'https://api call link'
    },
    timestamp: 15184.562748,
    type: 'XHR'
  }
}
{
  method: 'Network.dataReceived',
  params: {
    dataLength: 185,
    encodedDataLength: 0,
    requestId: '117.239',
    timestamp: 15184.562954
  }
}
{
  method: 'Network.dataReceived',
  params: {
    dataLength: 0,
    encodedDataLength: 203,
    requestId: '117.239',
    timestamp: 15184.563471
  }
}
{
  method: 'Network.loadingFinished',
  params: {
    encodedDataLength: 326,
    requestId: '117.239',
    shouldReportCorbBlocking: false,
    timestamp: 15184.552973
  }
}
```

To be noted, that when run locally outside of docker container this function works as expected and API call returns with status code: 200

P.S. Running it in Zelenium has the same results as locally in docker.

EDIT: Console logs contain follwoing error:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 ()
```

Comment: Update the question with the error stack trace.

Comment: There is no error stack trace. From backed everything is fine, and API call returns necesarry data, but this does not get back to docker container.

Comment: @DebanjanB Sorry, there was an error stack trace, if you meant from console logs. It is "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 ()"
Also, your provided link did not help me, as all of the resources have been loaded already.

Answer (score 0):

### status: 400

*status: 400* implies [400 Bad Request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/400) and *HTTP* `400 Bad Request` response status code indicates that the server cannot or will not process the request due to something that is perceived to be a client error e.g. a malformed request syntax, invalid request message framing, or deceptive request routing.

---

Some information interms of your code trials, the relevant HTML and the complete error stack trace would have helped us to analyze the issue in a better way. However, as per the discussion in [Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 ()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54027295/failed-to-load-resource-the-server-responded-with-a-status-of-400-while-tryi/54041236#54041236) it seems the [HTML DOM](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp) of the [webpage](https://www.instagram.com/) contains [AJAX](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp) and [JavaScript](https://www.javascript.com/) enabled elements.

So while you invoke `get()` method, before interacting with any of the elements on the particular webpage, you need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired *elements to be clickable* which will ensure that:

- The associated *JavaScript* and *AJAX Calls* have completed rendering the [DOM Tree](https://javascript.info/dom-nodes).
- The desired elements are **enabled** and **visible** to recognize **`click`** events propagated through *Selenium*.

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant discussions in:

- [Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (Bad Request) Spring JS call to Controller not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43170857/failed-to-load-resource-the-server-responded-with-a-status-of-400-bad-request/43309573)
- [spring post Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (Bad Request)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54686071/spring-post-failed-to-load-resource-the-server-responded-with-a-status-of-400)
- [Google adsense responding the server responded with a status of 400 ()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37236229/google-adsense-responding-the-server-responded-with-a-status-of-400)

---

### tl; dr

[Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 429 (Too Many Requests) and 404 (Not Found) with ChromeDriver Chrome through Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55979980/failed-to-load-resource-the-server-responded-with-a-status-of-429-too-many-req/55986553#55986553)